# Is there a benefit in having a multiprocessing.Pool where each process manages a ThreadPoolExecutor?

Tags: python, multithreading, performance, multiprocessing, gil

I am writing test automation suite on Python, which is executed in a parallel manner.
There are about 500 tests currently (and growing).

As we all know, when dealing with IO-bound operations in Python, it is recommended to use either asyncio, or a ThreadPoolExecutor / custom threading executor. When CPU-bound - multiprocessing.Pool is the recommended tool.
BUT!
When considering how the CPython implementation, due to the GIL, always uses a single core for multi-threading, and does not make use of an additional cores the machine may have (as other languages do when multi-threading in a multicore environment), then why not make the program to do use any additional cores, multithreading inside a process on each core?
Why not combine between the two, so that each process in the Pool spawns a ThreadPoolExecutor instance?

Won't this improve the parallel execution and shorten program running duration?
I mean, 80 threads on one core sounds a bit much, so why not make it 8 cores * 10 threads each?

What do i not know that is preventing me from understanding that what i am describing is a mutation?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to throw more compute power at an I/O-bound problem. That's not going to help.

Comment: @ user2357112 supports Monica 
why not though? instead of having 10 browsers open, i would have 40, so that not all 40 would share one GIL, but rather each chunk of 10 would share a GIL, summing up to a total of 4 GILs, thus making my program being able to lower the load on each GIL.

Is that not a benefit?

Comment: *"Why not combine between the two…"* That's what many server implementations do, in many languages.

Comment: @Klaus D. yeah but from what i understand, not in python. So that is my question, why shouldn't i do that, given that python doesn't?

Comment: Then your understanding is not correct. Examples: celery, gunicorn…

Comment: @Klaus D. Could you elaborate? got any recommended resources for studying the subject?